# If $S$ is a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S$ is linearly dependent, then there are more vectors in S than there are entries in the vector.

Tags: linear-algebra

> True or False: If $S$ is a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S$ is linearly dependent, then there are more vectors in S than there are entries in the vector.

I am having trouble answering this question since I haven't worked with many questions in $n$ dimensions, any idea how I could think about this question?

Comment: Try $S=\{0\}$ where $0$ is the zero vector in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: General advice: whatever works in $3$ or $4$ variables in linear algebra is probably more or less going to be the same in $n$. Sometimes there is extra rigidity in two dimensions - for example, formulas for the determinant and inverses are simple here, but if you understand how things work in $3$ dimensions, you usually understand everything either by a similar argument, or by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False: let n=3. If $S=\left\lbrace\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right)\right\rbrace$, $\vert S\vert=2<3=\dim_{\mathbb R} \mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Any set of vectors that includes zero is linearly dependent, so this is false even for 1-dimensional spaces. For another basic counterexample, take any pair of vectors such that one is a multiple of the other.

The converse is true, though: if you have more vectors than the dimension of the space, then they must be linearly dependent.